# Where does community and volunteer work belong on careers?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think that the profile page is missing a section for volunteer/community work or maybe we can change "writing" to "contributions"? Yes, I could put this in the Experience area but I think that is unclear and would make it harder to see the career path someone has followed. I could also put it in the "background" free-text area at the bottom but I don't really love that either because it doesn't have the nice structured input that would make sense for these types of entries.

This isn't a duplicate of any of the "show your code" functionality, I think it would be a nice complement to it.

The types of things I'd want to put in the list are:

- Participating on boards or meetings to help develop\improve curriculum for schools
- Industry Fellowships - helping to teach CS classes as an industry expert
- Speaking at events

I think these types of things can be very important to helping to make sure the company and developer have similar values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and work in some of this information into some of the existing portions, specific to what kind of work you're doing. I do think that some of this could be reworked. "Writing" -> "Publications" or "Media" to be a bit broader than just written word (for things like recorded talks and events). "Community" is an interesting one - it's hard to know what that would actually constitute.

This is something we may do down the line, but isn't in our immediate timeline. So for now, I generally defer to putting them in the "background" section or - if it is really standout - the "summary" of the CV. It's a good thought - I definitely agree that there should be some place to put this sort of thing.